# Why can't I seem to start a bounty on my question?

Tags: support, bounty

I would like to start a bounty on my own [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723707/how-is-the-quotient-group-related-to-the-direct-product-group/723731?noredirect=1#comment1514627_723731). But I only see the following link:
[image]

If I go to any other question, then I do see the link:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: I see the "start a bounty" link. Does refreshing help?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, it doesn't. Its a very odd problem. I've the same problem in both Chrome and Firefox, so it doesn't have anything to do with the browser I'm using (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the reason is the following (quote from the [FAQ on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)):

> If you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, [your minimum spend is 100 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826) (not 50).

And, of course:

> You must have at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, and at least as much reputation as the bounty amount.

At the moment you have less than 100 reputation points, so you cannot start a bounty of 100 points.

Comment: That is very unfortunate...